# LaunchUriAsync Windows calculator - first time

Tags: win-universal-app

Perhaps this is expected behavior, but the programmatic launching of built-in applications in Windows 10 is scarce for anything aside from settings app, maps, and contacts, in my experience - and I could use some help on this.

I am launching the stock Windows Calculator from within the application.  I took some guesses as the Uri and it appears to work - except on the first launch.  When we get a new device, the first time the app is run and the calculator is attempted to be launched, it wants to get an app from the store (which the end users will not have access to) - it does not even offer the built-in calculator as a choice.  **If the calculator is opened manually, even once, it just works from that point on.**  Is there something else I could/should be doing?  Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I would like to have it work the first time (a setting on the device?), or at least offer the built-in calculator as a choice.

Here is the code I am using:

```
private async void LaunchCalculatorAsync(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
    options.TreatAsUntrusted = false;
    options.DesiredRemainingView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ViewSizePreference.UseNone;
    await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("calculator:"), options);
}
```

From running a list of installed apps on the device, I see the calculator listed: Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe.  I have been unsuccessful with attempting to provide the PreferredApplicationPackageFamilyName using `options.PreferredApplicationPackageFamilyName = "WindowsCalculator";`
I have tried with/without the "Microsoft." as well as with/without the odd string of characters.

Comment: Tested it, I wrote an app and only deploy this app to the local machine, it can still be launched from other app, and I also tried other default apps which are not launched before, it works fine. What is your OS version?

Comment: Thank you for trying it out.  I am running Build 10240 and that is what the app is targeting.  Now, I'm looking at the device that I can duplicate this on and it is running version 1511, Build 10586.104.

Comment: OK. My OS version is 10568, please let me know your test result.

Answer (score -1):

You may get the demo from Microsoft in GitHub,
[Association launching sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AssociationLaunching)

Hope this can help you.

```
private async void LaunchUriWithWarning()
    {
        // Create the URI to launch from a string.
        var uri = new Uri(UriToLaunch.Text);

        // Configure the warning prompt.
        var options = new LauncherOptions() { TreatAsUntrusted = true };

        // Launch the URI.
        bool success = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);
        if (success)
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser("URI launched: " + uri.AbsoluteUri, NotifyType.StatusMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser("URI launch failed.", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Many of your answers are link only. Try to be more specific and elaborated in answering the questions.

Comment: Update with Source Code.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.